# Unable to access Bootstrap dropdown with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown in my frontend looking like this:

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right text-left" id="dropdown_menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" id="dropdown_change_pwd">Change Password</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}" id="dropdown_logout">Logout</a>
    </div>
```

I want to access these buttons with selenium in python. I tried to access it like this:

```
class SearchPage:
_CHANGE_PWD_DROPDOWN = (By.ID, 'dropdown_change_pwd')
_LOGOUT_DROPDOWN = (By.ID, 'dropdown_logout')
_DROPDOWN = (By.ID, 'dropdown_menu')

def __init__(self, browser):
    self.browser = browser

def logout(self):
    time.sleep(5)
    dropdown = self.browser.find_element(*self._DROPDOWN)
    dropdown.click()
    logout = self.browser.find_element(*self._LOGOUT_DROPDOWN)
    logout.click()
```

However I always end up with:

```
response = {'status': 400, 'value': '{\n\t"value" : \n\t{\n\t\t"error" : "element not interactable",\n\t\t"message" : "Element is not displayed",\n\t\t"stacktrace" : ""\n\t}\n}\r\n'}
```

It seems like Selenium can't deal with the bootstrap dropdown. How can I still click any of the elements in this dropdown?

If there is no direct solution for doing this, is there some way for an workaround?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the *Logout* element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right.text-left"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.dropdown-item#dropdown_logout"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right text-left']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='dropdown-item' and @id='dropdown_logout']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, both of these result in a TimeoutException.

Comment: @MarcB. You haven't even provided the anchor element within the question which you have used in your answer.

Comment: You are right. There was no way for you to answer my question. I realized that afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

My dropdown in total looked like this:

```
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="welcome_user" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Welcome, {{ session['current_user']['name'] }}</a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right text-left">
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" id="dropdown_change_pwd">Change Password</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}" id="dropdown_logout">Logout</a>
       </div>
    </li>
```

First I had to access the **upper** element with:

```
   dropdown = self.browser.find_elemnt(By.ID, 'welcome_user')
   dropdown.click()
```

And then I can access the link like this:

```
    dropdown_logout = self.browser.find_elemnt(By.ID, 'dropdown_logout')
    dropdown_logout.click()
```